# Read Excel charts in Python

Tags: python, excel, charts

I have an excel file including some charts. The file is big and complicated and The data is coming from an external source, it means that the data is not included in the excel file discretely, and the only way to see the data is to extract it from the charts. I know how to do this in Excel, but I am looking for a way to read the data from the charts in python(Instead of reading the tabular data).

Comment: It's generally a good idea to share some your code.

Comment: I found a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513145/fastest-way-to-read-large-excel-xlsx-files-to-parallelize-or-not?r=SearchResults&s=7|40.9358

Comment: @AnkitKante I don't have a code.. I'm looking for one. All the example I can find they just read tabular data. like pd.read_excel().

Comment: @AnnZen doesn't answer my question.